# How can I determine in JS if a function/method exists in IE7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I wrote a quick and dirty logger as a jQuery plugin...

```
(function($){   
    $.log = function(debug) {       
        if (console.debug) {            
            console.debug(debug);           
        };      
    };
})(jQuery);
```

It works fine in Firefox, but in IE7, I'm getting the error...

> console.debug is null or not an object

How do I perform a function exists in JavaScript that's compatible with IE7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`console.debug` is specific to Firebug, which runs under Firefox.

You need to check if `window.console` is available before checking for `console.log`!

Here's your code reworked with no errors:

```
(function($){
    $.log = function(debug) {
        if (window.console && console.debug) {
                console.debug(debug);
        };
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: ie8 dev tools also has a console

Comment: So does Safari with developer mode turned on.

Comment: Fair points, I don't develop in either so haven't really used their console tools very much.

Comment: I've gone with your solution. Thanks Jason!

Comment: I would also fallback to creating a hidden div in the footer for browsers without a console. Then at least you can see the log info.

Answer (score 3):

Check if console is defined, then check if debug is a function:

```
if (typeof(console) != 'undefined' && typeof(console.debug) == 'function'){
  //...
}
```

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure that would throw an error if console was not defined, you can do either

window.console ( specifying the "namespace" or owner object ) or
typeof console == 'object' && typeof console.debug == 'function'

Comment: his modified one should work. though id prefer mine ( if it works ) since its a one liner.

Answer (score 3):

```
$.log = window.console && console.debug ? function(debug) { console.debug(debug); } : function(){};
```

Variations:

```
$.log = function( debug ) {
    if ( window.console && console.debug ) { 
        console.debug( debug )
    }
}

$.log = function( msg ) {
    if ( window.console ) {
       if ( console.debug ) console.debug ( msg ) 
       else if ( console.log ) console.log ( msg )
    }
}

$.log = function( msg ) {
    if ( typeof console === 'object' && typeof console.debug === 'function' ) { 
       console.debug( msg )
    }
}

$.log = 'console' in window && console.debug ? function(m){console.debug(m)}:function(){}

$.log = function() {
     if ( 'console' in window ) {
         console.debug ? function(m){console.debug(m)} : ( console.log ? function(m){console.log(m)} : function(){}
     }
}

$.log = window.log = function(m){ if(window.console && console.debug) console.debug(m) }
```

Comment: Whoa, went all out on that response, huh? :)

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are all correct, but you're going to have the side effect of your log statements being converted from an arguments object into an array, and your output will look (something) like this:

["my", "debug", "statement"]

To fix that you need to forward the arguments object and keep it intact:

```
$.log = function() { // note no arguments used
    if ( window.console && console.debug ) { 
        console.debug.apply(console, arguments )
    }
}
```

Now the output will look like:

```
My debug statement
```